# JqGrid selector options 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, django, jqgrid

I'm adding a new field to a jqGrid that acts as a foreign key between tables, but the selector that I'm using is just a bunch of options that all say 'undefined'.  I've used the methods below on other places of my site, but I don't get why it isn't working here.  This is a django site.

view:

```
def view_export(request):
    #handle what to do if it's a POST request
    #set other variables in infoDict
    infoDict['tempalte_choices'] = get_template_choices()
    return renderutils.render_response("export", infoDict, "export")

def get_template_choices():
    choices = []
    for template in Template.objects.all():
        choices.append((template.id, template.code))
    #choices is now a list of tuples (id, display code)
    return choices
```

JS:

```
templateChoices = "{{template_choices}}";
baseGrid = new BaseGrid("export-grid", {'edit':true});
#set the other jqGrid attributes
baseGrid.colNames = ['Code', 'Name', 'Status', 'Template']
baseGrid.colModel = [
    {name:'code', index:'code', width:70 },
    {name:'name', index:'name', width:120},
    {name:'status', index:'status', width:50},
    {name:'template', index:'template', width:100, editable:true, edittype:'select', editoption:{value: templateChoices} }
    ]
```

Comment: Look at the typo: `tempalte_choices` should be `template_choices` in your export view

Comment: infoDict['tempalte_choices'] is just a typo here, it's spelled correctly in the code